# SQL Server foreign characters equal empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

We have a query looking for empty values in a column, but it is returning results where the column is not empty.

As an example, this query returns true:

```
IF N'ការវិនិយោគបរទេស នៅជប៉ុន ធ្លាក់ចុះនៅឆ្នាំ២០១៧ នៅតែជាបញ្ហាធំបំផុត របស់ពិភពលោក' = N''
    PRINT 'true'
ELSE
    PRINT 'false';
```

I suspect it may be a collation issue, but I've tried forcing various collations and the result is still true.

```
IF N'ការវិនិយោគបរទេស នៅជប៉ុន ធ្លាក់ចុះនៅឆ្នាំ២០១៧ នៅតែជាបញ្ហាធំបំផុត របស់ពិភពលោក' = N'' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI
    PRINT 'true'
ELSE
    PRINT 'false';
```

Comment: Try a binary Collation. As you chose `Arabic_CI_AI` then `Arabic_BIN` seems appropriate [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c80f40495276bc1a8ab67e21a92d1f9f). You can get a list of binary collations with `SELECT [Name], [Description] FROM fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE '%BIN%';`

Comment: Alternatively, if by "empty string" you truly mean "a string with no characters" (not just a string containing whitespace) testing for `DATALENGTH(value) = 0` would do regardless of type or collation. (`LEN(value) = 0` is subtly different, as it ignores trailing spaces.)

Comment: Both alternatives in the above comments work, but I'd still like to understand the underlying behavior that causes this to happen.

Comment: It happens because most of SQL Server's collations are version 80, which contain no information for comparing Khmer, and so all those characters will just be treated as equivalent to nothing at all ("sorted lowest"). Binary collations always work (as they only consider code points), as would collations like `Arabic_100_CI_AS` (version 100 collation) or, indeed, `Khmer_100_CI_AS` (specifically for Khmer).

Comment: @JeroenMostert If you combine your two comment together, I think that would make a pretty acceptable answer to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The text you want to compare seems to be Khmer, not Arabic, so you should use a `Khmer_100_*` collation.

Have a look at this TSQL snippet

```
declare @coll table (
    name nvarchar(50),
    khmerSupported bit
)

declare @text nvarchar(200) = N'ការវិនិយោគបរទេស នៅជប៉ុន ធ្លាក់ចុះនៅឆ្នាំ២០១៧ នៅតែជាបញ្ហាធំបំផុត របស់ពិភពលោក'

declare @name nvarchar(50), @sql nvarchar(500)

declare c cursor for 
select name from sys.fn_helpcollations()
where name like 'khm%'

open c

fetch c into @name
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin

set @sql = 'select ''' + @name + ''', case when @text = N'''' COLLATE ' + @name + ' then 0 else 1 end'
print @sql
    insert into @coll (name, khmerSupported)
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@text NVARCHAR(200)', @text=@text

    fetch c into @name
end

close c
deallocate c

select Name, KhmerSupported from @coll
```

and experiment with the collations query.

Use `select Name, KhmerSupported from @coll where KhmerSupported=1` to find all collations supporting Khmer comparison.